# how to convert simple query with conditions into dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have tables like

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #t
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tt') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #tt
GO
CREATE TABLE #t(ID INT,Name varchar(10))
insert into #t (ID,name)values (1,'mohan'),(2,'mohan')

CREATE TABLE #tt(ID INT,Name varchar(10))
insert into #tt (ID,name)values (1,'Raju'),(2,'ram')
```

and i have created a procedure where i need to call based on status

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Getresult
(
@statusval char(2)
)
AS 
BEGIN 
IF @statusval = '01'
BEGIN 
Select * from #t
END 
IF @statusval = '02'
BEGIN 
Select * from #tt
END
IF @statusval = '00'
BEGIN 
Select P.ID,P.Name from (
Select * from #t
UNION ALL
Select * from #tt)P
END
END
EXEC usp_Getresult '00'=> '01' or '02'
```

in my original procedure it have more conditions i just don't want write in if conditions i want this convert convert into dynamic query even i know to convert into dynamic but if i have multiple conditions then how i need to proceed

Answer (score 4):

If 2 tables schema are identical, I would just go for normal query to have the great intelliSence

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Getresult
(
    @statusval char(2)
)
AS 
BEGIN 

    Select * from #t WHERE @statusval IN ('00', '01')
    UNION ALL
    Select * from #tt WHERE @statusval IN ('00', '02')

END
```

Comment: i'm looking not into performance side just want eliminate if conditions @eric

Comment: @mohan111 Not sure what do you mean by eliminate `if`, there is not a single `if` in the sample

Comment: This query certainly eliminates all of those if statements.

Comment: here i gave you sample example but my original query have different columns with more input parameters..in this scenario it is fine but seriously looking for dynamic

Comment: @mohan111 You mean your query return different columns for some conditions? Or just identical?